# Reverse an Array in F#

Tags: arrays, list, f#, reverse

Is there any other way to reverse an Array in F# without using the array.rev function and without copying the original array, maybe similar to how you would reverse a List.

```
let rev (lst : List<'T>) =
  let length = List.length lst
  seq { for i in (length-1) .. -1 .. 0 do yield lst.[i] }
  |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Unfortunately *'more beautiful'* is very opinion-based. Please clarify the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: just asking for another way to reverse an Array

Comment: *Without copying* means reversing the original array instead of creating reversed array?

Comment: I would reverse a list by calling the `List.rev` function. LOL. Array.rev and List.rev are both O(N), as is any other reasonable algorithm. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-collection-types#table-of-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new array, the only choice is to mutate elements of the original array. Change them in place.

To reverse, just swap the first element with the last, second - with second to last, and so on:

```
let rev arr =
    let len = Array.length arr
    for i in 0..(len/2 - 1) do
        let x = arr.[i]
        arr.[i] <- arr.[len-i-1]
        arr.[len-i-1] <- x
    arr
```